How to password protect a directory that contains an OpenCart shop
I have installed OpenCart in a folder on a hosted server. The reason why it's in a folder and not the root, is that I only want people who login to have access to the shop and stay logged in while shopping. This has nothing to do with logging into OpenCart as they would have to do that as well to see the prices. I just don't want anyone to see the shop before logging in.
I have resorted to using the .htaccess .htpasswd method, which seems to work fine, to an extent. There is a popup that wants you to login, and when you do, it takes you to a blank page, not the shop. So it works fine on the directory, but once logged in, there is nothing. I'm wondering if it's because there is other stuff in the .htaccess file from OpenCart. I'm very new at all of this, and therefore I don't know what any of that stuff does.
The problem is, that it appears that OpenCart, in the .htaccess file, hides the urls, so instead of going to an index.html page, there is nothing.
I added this to the .htaccess file from another post on stack overflow:
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /path/to/the/directory/you/are/protecting/.htpasswd  
require valid-user  

And I changed the path of course. But when that wasn't working, it said to try adding this:
\<Directory /path/to/the/directory/of/htaccess\>  
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
AllowOverride All  
\</Directory\>  

and again, I changed the path. But then I noticed that perhaps that might interfere with other things that were already in the file such as:
## No directory listings
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## No-Referrer-Header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
</IfModule>

## Suppress mime type detection in browsers for unknown types and prevent FLOC
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  Header always set Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks

## Prevent Directory listing
Options -Indexes

## Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

## SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
## If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/
RewriteBase /testing2/
## Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp|js|css|svg)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Also, some of these things said to restart the server, but I don't have access to that. But because I'm new at this, I don't know if any of these things work against each other. If it had been a clean, new .htaccess file, I could understand it would be simpler, but because it already has things in it because of OpenCart, then maybe it's not so simple after all. Is there another way to keep people from seeing the products, not just the prices in OpenCart (which is their standard option)?

The Directory can't be used in .htaccess to begin with. And no, since .htaccess files are read on every request, you don't need to restart the web server, to make changes made in .htaccess to become effective.

Adding the password protection, should not really change anything about how the rest of it works. Please add more details to the question - like, which URL you are actually requesting, when you get that "blank page." And you should also go and check if the Apache error log, the PHP error log, plus whatever OpenCart itself might have regarding error logging, have anything to say about this.

In your opencart settings there is an option to hide prices until a customer is logged in.
IF you actually want to hide the entire store and force login you can add the following code to your /store/catalog/controller/common/header.php at the top:
if (!$this->customer->isLogged() && !in_array($this->request->get['route'], ['account/login', 'account/register'])) {
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}

Opencart 4.x solution:
if (!$this->customer->isLogged() && (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || !in_array($this->request->get['route'], ['account/login', 'account/register']))) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', true));
}

Reset your htaccess back to what it was, its a bad way to manage this, if your still having issues loading the site even with default htaccess of opencart you need to make sure your path is set right here:
RewriteBase /testing2/


Thank you so much, I'm looking at this file now. The first line says: namespace Opencart\Catalog\Controller\Common; and then there is a class called Header. Do I put this code before that line, or in the class Header?

put it after the function header() { so that its the first thing after the function call. Dont forget to upvote my answer if you could be so kind :)

I put an answer in below because I had to paste several errors. I was hoping you could take a look at that.

I tried putting it in different spots in the code but I keep getting errors. The first error, when put at the end:
Warning: Undefined property: Opencart\System\Engine\Autoloader::$customer in testing2/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 98Call to a member function isLogged() on null: in testing2/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 98
I get the same error if I put it inside the function, and the second error if put at the top:
syntax error, unexpected token "if", expecting "function" or "const": in testing2/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 13

what version of opencart do you have?

I have version 4.0.2.3

it needs to go right after the index function, here: https://webdesires.dev/u/241021/Code_Qwszom1LGf.png

ive added the 4.x solution which is slightly different.
